# formula for finding perimeter of half circle

Tags: geometry, circles, gre-exam

i was looking for this problem

http://www.majortests.com/gre/problem_solving_expl.php?exp=50313039243130243330
and was surprised if it is correct,we know that  circumference or perimeter of  circle is equal to
$C=\pi*D=2*\pi*R$
but what about perimeter of half circle?i found following link
http://www.mathvillage.info/node/159

which says that perimeter of half circle is 
$c=\pi*D/2+D$

where $D$ is diameter of course,but in problem,link of  which i have posted,it is not considered and it said that perimeter of half circle is just  $\pi*D/2$,in case of this test come on GRE exam,i should now of course which formula is correct,so please help me to determine there is  error made in formula  $\pi*D/2+D$ or what? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked question, we are just interested in the upper half of the circle and not at all the base (diameter). So, that is why we are just using the perimeter as $\pi*r$.

Every formula is used in certain context. And understanding context is more important than the formula.

ADDED- Perimeter can be considered as the length of a tape required to cover the given figure. So, now i guess you can see which formula is to be used.

Comment: so could you explain it more detailed?

Comment: i could not understand one thing,perimeter of white region is equal to perimeter of rectangle minus perimeter of half circle right?

Comment: In the question, had they asked to find out the perimeter of the half circle/ perimeter of the shaded region, that sure would have been &\pi*r+2r&

Comment: But we are asked to find the perimeter of the part which is not shaded. which is equal to 3 sides of the rectangle + arc of the half cicle

Comment: note that full perimeter of the half circle is not equal to the perimeter of the arc. or for that matter, full perimeter of the half circle is not equal to the perimeter of the base. I hope i am clear.

Comment: cone also has the similar property. its lateral surface area (that is cloth required to make a tent) is pi*r*l, and its full surface area (actual area of the space the tent is covering, we'll add base here) is pi*r*l+pi*r^2

Comment: or  perimeter of rectangle minus perimeter of half circle correct?

Comment: Correct. Perimeter of the white region= perimeter of the rectangle minus 'full' perimeter of the semi-circle.

Comment: full perimeter of  semi circle is $\pi*D/2+D$ right?

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: if i subtract then i will get 26-($\pi*D/2+D$) correct

Comment: then why is plus in answer?it should be plus right

Comment: ok, i see that won't give us the answer. because rectangle-circle formula can be used for area, not perimeter. For perimeter, we would have to consider the actual sides/curves of the required region, which in this case is 3 sides+arc.

Comment: so in this case  three length+$\pi*D/2$?

Comment: without any doubt.

Comment: i should never  mix in each other difference of finding   perimeter and  area

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter of a semicircle is, in fact, $\pi * \frac{D}{2} + D$. There is the $\pi * \frac{D}{2}$ portion coming from the curved part, which is half of the total perimeter of a circle, as would be expected, and there is the $D$, which comes from the flat side of the semicircle, which, as it is a diameter of the circle, clearly has length $D$.

Comment: so it means that,solution is wrong right?

Comment: It means that which solution is wrong?